# arrange array with condition in java

Tags: java, arrays

My inputs are like:

```
String[] a = {"true","false","false","false","true","CC","true","false","false","CC","true","false","false","false"};

int[] b = {0,1,2,3,5,99,0,5,4,99,0,89,6,5};
```

Requirement is whenever there is any *true* or *CC* in array a[] I have to produce the same value corresponding to the same index in the output array, and if there is *false* in the array **a[]** the corresponding value should be add to the output array.

For this case output should be :

```
output[] = {0,6,5,99,0,9,99,0,100};
```

Please suggest. I have tried with many look and if-else conditions combination but not able to get the required result.

My code is:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ArrayTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] a = {"true","false","false","false","true","CC","true","false","false","CC","true","false","false","false"};
    int[] b = {0,1,2,3,5,99,0,5,4,99,0,89,6,5};

    ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();

    int sum=0;
    int flg =0;
    for(int i =0; i<a.length;i++){

        if(a[i].equals("true") && sum ==0 ){
            ar.add(b[i] );
        }
        else if (a[i].equals("true") && sum!=0){
            ar.add(sum);
            ar.add(b[i]);
            sum =0;
        }

        else if(a[i].equals("false")){
            sum= sum+b[i];          
        }
        else if((a.length-1 == i) && sum !=0){
            ar.add(sum );
            sum=0;
        }
        else if(a[i].equals("CC")){
            ar.add(b[i]);
        }
     }

     System.out.println(ar);
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does "the corresponding value" mean? I can't understand your explanation. Where do all the output values come from? What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: He wants to replace sequences of numbers, which have "false" in the same position in string array, with their sum.

Comment: `I have tried with many look and if-else conditions` post the one that gets closest to what you want, and lets start from there.

Comment: String[] a = {"true","false","false","false","true","CC","true","false","false","CC","true","false","false","false"};
  int[] b = {0,1,2,3,5,99,0,5,4,99,0,89,6,5};
  ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
  int sum=0;
  int flg =0;
  for(int i =0; i<a.length;i++){
   if(a[i].equals("true") && sum ==0 ){
    ar.add(b[i] );
   }
   else if (a[i].equals("true") && sum!=0){
 ar.add(sum);
 ar.add(b[i]);
 sum =0;
 }
 else if(a[i].equals("false")){
 sum= sum+b[i];
}
 else if((a.length-1 == i) && sum !=0){
 ar.add(sum );
 sum=0;
 }
 else if(a[i].equals("CC")){
 ar.add(b[i]);
 }
 }System.out.println(ar);
 }

Comment: Hi ,

I have added my code. Please suggest.

Comment: It sounds like you need another array to store the output.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me:

```
public class ArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] a = {"true","false","false","false","true","CC","true","false","false","CC","true","false","false","false"};
        int[] b = {0,1,2,3,5,99,0,5,4,99,0,89,6,5};

        ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();

        int sum=0;
        boolean isFalse = false;
        for(int i =0; i<a.length;i++){

            isFalse = false;
            if(a[i].equals("true") || a[i].equals("CC")) {
                if (sum != 0)
                    ar.add(sum);
                ar.add(b[i]);
                sum = 0;
            }
            else if(a[i].equals("false")){
                sum= sum+b[i];
                isFalse = true;
            }

        }
        if (isFalse)
            ar.add(sum);
        System.out.println(ar);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 6, 5, 99, 0, 9, 99, 0, 100]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = {"true","false","false","false","true","CC","true","false","false","CC","true","false","false","false"};

        int[] b = {0,1,2,3,5,99,0,5,4,99,0,89,6,5};
        List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        boolean moveNext = true;
        int sum = 0;
        for(i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++){
            if( a[i].equals("true") || a[i].equals("CC") ){
                if(!moveNext){
                    output.add(sum);
                    sum = 0;
                    moveNext = true;

                }
                output.add(b[i]);
            }
            if( a[i].equals("false")){
                sum += b[i];
                moveNext = false;
            }
        }
        if(!moveNext)
            output.add(sum);

        for(i = 0 ; i < output.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(output.get(i));
        }

    }
```